# My ASP.NET Core API not returning all rows

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core API is only returning the first two rows out of 40.

I have tried

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

It sent VS code in to an endless loop. Any ideas on where to look to fix this? I am using the browser and postman to consume the api with the same results.

```
[EnableCors]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Fuaxclient>> GetClient()
{
    return _context.clientList;
}
```

I am expecting to get proper json code of about 48 rows. Instead I'm getting 2 rows and broken json. I get this error from FireFox Web Console

```
error: null​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​message: "Http failure response for https://fuaxclientapi.azurewebsites.net/api/fuaxclient: 500 Internal Server Error"​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​ok: false
​status: 500
​statusText: "Internal Server Error"
​url: "https://fuaxclientapi.azurewebsites.net/api/fuaxclient"
```

The API is still running if you would like to try the API to see what I'm talking about.
​

Comment: Can you show the action for the `fuaxclientapi`?

Comment: What do the logs on azure say. If you are generating a 500 error it should have generated a server side log.

Comment: The API `https://fuaxclientapi.azurewebsites.net/api/fuaxclient` is returning invalid JSON structure. You would need to append the string with `]` in the end of the response in order to parse this JSON string properly.

Comment: How woulds i access that log? I'm still learning to navigate azore dash board

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much digging and researching and banging my head on the desk, I have found my issue. I had NULL in my database and the API stopped at the NULL.

Answer (score -1):

```
status: 500
​statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

As the error `500` itself suggests there error is on the server, in this case the url( endpoint api) stated as `https://fuaxclientapi.azurewebsites.net/api/fuaxclient` has issue.

It returns invalid json as validated [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

The return value need to be fixed in the api.

Comment: I beleive https://fuaxclientapi.azurewebsites.net/api/fuaxclient is the op's code in the question. Your answer to "how do i track down this problem" is "fix your problem"

Comment: When i request single "clients" it returns correct json. Why would the bulk query be any different?